# Hangfire cron expression that never runs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

Is it possible to write a CRON expression for Hangfire that never triggers? I used the one proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255963/4556938) and it gives me next execution in 22 years. Is there any permanent/more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they will be supporting "Manual Jobs" in `V1.7`
regrettably there is no release date for it

Feature: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/382

Milestone: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/milestone/50